# Divisibility problem, number theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is $10^{is}-1$ divisible by $10^{s}-1$ there i, s are natural numbers. If so, how do I prove it? Thanks for help, I've delt with it. How I should go about proving this a bit harder divisibility problem?

I need to prove that $10^s+1$ divides both $10^{2ks}-1$ and $10^{(2k-1)s}+1$

I've tackled that problem too. Thank you Math Gems for showing me the way :)

Comment: There is nothing special about 10. Why don't you check that $x^s-1|x^{is}-1$

Comment: Hint: let $\, x = 10^s\,$ in $\,x-1\,$ divides $\,x^i-1.\ $ Or $\ 10^s\equiv 1\:\Rightarrow\:10^{si} = (10^s)^i\equiv 1^i\equiv 1 \ \ $

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What happens when you multiply out $(x^s - 1)(1 + x^s + x^{2s} + \cdots + x^{(i-1)s})$?